# Executing a SQL query multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-administration

How to run the same query multiple times in SQL Server?

Simple example, I have a query

```
select * from sys.databases
```

I wanted to run it N times, because I wanted to return the data in a dashboard in "real time", until I stopped the execution, the select would need to continue running "example: as SQL Server Profiler does, while I don't stop, it keeps bringing the information in the screen".

What would be the best way for this type of situation?

Remembering that the query and SQL Server profiler are just examples.

Comment: What application will serve as the dashboard, e.g. a website, a custom C#/Windows app or only an iPhone app? What latency is tolerable, e.g. can the data shown be 10ms old or 10s old? How many dashboards will there be, e.g. is it one 1200-inch display over the factory floor or 1200 users scattered across the solar system? All of these issues, and more, compound one another. If the data must be less than 10ms old, but the network delays add up to 150ms then you're done. If there are multiple users then you'll want a way to share the results of the query without running it for each user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a job and insert your query to run, and under the schedule set the timings to execute your query.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please goto SQL Agent, right click on jobs and  create a new job.  A window will appear, give the job name and now click on steps and then click on new. Enter your query and test your query by clicking on parse. Then go to schedule and set the timings and recurring to execute your job. I hope i have clearly explained.

Answer (score 0):

Because your dashboard code must poll the dbms every so often to get the latest data, you must decide how often as part of your system design.

Once a minute? That is very often to poll the data. But only you can decide how out-of-date your dashboard users will tolerate.

Whatever you do, avoid promising "real time" if you possibly can. We programmers can't deliver on that promise with polling the database.